# Sunrise / Check time

Tags: java, timespan

For my app I use a sunriseCalc-lib. 
This lib calculates the sunrise-time and returns a string like this 12:20.
Is it possible to check if the current time is later than the sunrise time?
I have the following code:

```
        Location location = new Location("52.3496752", "4.6211921");
        DateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        SunriseSunsetCalculator calculator = new SunriseSunsetCalculator(location, "Europe/Berlin");
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();

        Date dawn = newDateFormat.parse(calculator.getOfficialSunriseForDate(date));
        Date dusk = newDateFormat.parse(calculator.getOfficialSunsetForDate(date));
```

Comment: oops, sunrise @ `12:20`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Date().after(dawn)`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29

Answer (score 1):

If you have Date objects already just use the `before()` and `after()` methods on those objects.